# Capturing and displaying exec/shell_exec periodic output?

Tags: php

You can easily use `exec()` or `shell_exec()` to execute a system command, like `ls -l /var/www/mysite` and then output the result of the command.

How would one execute and display the result of a command that periodically prints information out to the console?

You have a simply Python script. If you run the script from the console, it simply prints out some type of information to the console every 10 seconds forever until you force-quit the script.

How could use PHP to execute this python command and somehow capture and stream the output into the browser in realtime? Is something like this possible? I'm thinking there would have to be some sort of Ajax involved but I'm not sure.

I tried doing something like this:

```
python myscript.py > output.txt
```

And then I was planning on maybe using Ajax to periodically `tail` or `cat` the content of the `output.txt` and display in the browser. But `output.txt` doesn't appear to have any content added to it until after the script has been force-quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see any output to `output.txt` because it's being buffered. For python there's an option to make it line-buffered. From the manpage:

```
       -u     Force  the  binary I/O layers of stdin, stdout and stderr to be unbuffered.  The text I/O layer will still be
              line-buffered.
```

So your command would then become:

```
python -u myscript.py > output.txt
```

For PHP the [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function should help you.

Comment: It looks like that is the right approach but PHP is still buffering things I think... Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Jakobud, did you try manually calling `flush` in your PHP script?

Comment: Ah I haven't tried that. I was go that direction and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Check this question as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output, it might have the function needed.