# Executing bash script via PhP gives a different result compared to executing manually

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell, raspberry-pi

As the title says, when i try manually executing the script by double clicking and pressing execute through terminal. It works correctly

However when i run my php script or typing the php into the terminal window

```
/usr/bin/php start_cam.php
```

It locks up (the command doesn't finish with the "$", "$" does not show in terminal window  to show it has ended the task and it doesn't work correctly

Below is my php script

```
<?php
        $command =escapeshellcmd("/bin/bash cmd_start_cam.sh");
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        echo $output;
        echo  "php_startcam2";

?>
```

Below is my bash script(cmd_start_cam.sh)

```
!/bin/bash

echo 'running start camera script' 
cd
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
cd 
cd RPi_Cam_Web_Interface 
sudo chmod u+x RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh

sudo ./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh stop 
sudo ./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh start
echo 'complete start camera script'
```

Note: I use cd to ensure that im at my root directory as there where the files are. As its working via manual execution, do not think there a path issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you

Update: this is the error im experiencing output by the terminal command window:

i think i am experiencing a broken pipe as after my bash script command `echo 'complete start camera script'`

terminal window output  `cmd_start_cam.sh: line 12: echo: write error: Broken Pipe` and doesn't end with a `$` like it should on normal execution

By the way this is running on raspberry pi 2

> **Update Solved/Solution:**

Thanks to @ikra insight on checking the apache log file, which lead me to discover that the root cause was permission access. www-data needs to be added to the sudoers file.

1. Instructions on backing up and editing sudoers file :http://raspbypi.com/enabling-the-sudo-command-for-a-new-user/
2. sudo visudo
3. add this at the end of the file www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
4. Press CTRL+X and press yes
5. login and logout to ensure permission is now set.
6. If your sudoer file gets corrupted: type this in terminal window to fix whatever text you have typed wrongly `pkexec visudo` .(Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

Comment: Those `sudo` prompts may be asking for a password.  PHP isn't sending any input, so it just sits there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat hmm but when i manually type out those commands without a script but with sudo it works. Ok but say it requires password, how do i parse password via php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ikra insight on checking the apache log file, which lead me to discover that the root cause was permission access. www-data needs to be added to the sudoers file.

1. Instructions on backing up and editing sudoers file :http://raspbypi.com/enabling-the-sudo-command-for-a-new-user/
2. sudo visudo
3. add this at the end of the file www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
4. Press CTRL+X and press yes
5. login and logout to ensure permission is now set.
6. If your sudoer file gets corrupted: type this in terminal window to fix whatever text you have typed wrongly `pkexec visudo` .(Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('php start_cam.php');
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```

You can maintain the bash script and simply trigger it like my example. However seeing the script is just a bunch of bash command, why not trigger them directly into the shell, that way you can handle the return and any exceptions.

In terms of security this is far better than running apache as root or the wide open sudo permissions you list in your solution update. But letting PHP anywhere near root is always tricky.

The project i built achieves a root bash shell in one of 2 ways:

1) You allow apache the right to sudo python.

OR

2) You pass root credentials to the object every time you need a shell with root setup.

Pick your poison. :) Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should either check:

- [SUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) your shell-scripts, which are run with `sudo`
- and make sure everything is OK with current directory (and `PATH`) for your PHP script.

Comment: i dont get the SUID part, what if i have set permision 777 to the file ? do i still need SUID?

Comment: @peekaboo This question https://superuser.com/questions/440363/can-i-make-a-script-always-execute-as-root will make it clear, I believe

Comment: hmmm judging from his other solution  i might as well just chown the file change owner from www-data:www-data to root:root

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your script with php-cli and put this line at the beginning to see what is happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -ddisplay_errors=E_ALL
```

Do

```
chmod 700 myscript.php
```

and run it this way

```
$ ./myscript.php
```

If you want to run it under your apache server, just insert this function after the opening php tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

will do the same.

To pass your password to the sudo command, use `sudo -S *command* < <(echo -e "*pass*\n")` in your script shell. However, that is a bad idea, because everyone who can access your script can get your password.

I guess your script starts your camera, if `sudo ./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh start` is a stream resource, then the issue is that `shell_exec(./myscript.sh)` has a limited buffer value, thus it can't handle the response of your script shell.

Try to use `popen()` instead of `shell_exec()`

I found an interesting link, which addresses an issue that is somewhat similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109859/5280812

Comment: where do i put this line? `#!/usr/bin/php -ddisplay_errors=E_ALL` ?terminal command window or my script or php file?

Comment: i think i am experiencing a broken pipe as after my bash script command `echo 'complete start camera script' ` terminal output  `cmd_start_cam.sh: line 12: echo: write error: Broken Pipe` and doesn't end with a `$` like it should on normal execution

Comment: ths line should appear at the beginning of your script `#!/usr/bin/php -ddisplay_errors=E_ALL`

Comment: but my script is a bash script wouldn't that change the interpreter?

Comment: i meant add it in your php script. try to remove the line 12 in your script shell, since it's not critical

Comment: i fixed a little mistake i made in the **sudo** command. try this instead `sudo -S command < <(echo -e "passwd\n")`

Comment: manually executing using `./script_name.php` works but if i do `/usr/bin/php script_name.php` it would get stuck any ideas? even after using popen

Comment: What `sudo ./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh start` did exactly?

Comment: sorry was busy the past few days but i have solve the issue, your tips helped me out will post the solution.