# HTML not showing characters

Tags: php, html, firefox, lighttpd

I'm running lighttpd 1.4.35 on Debian 8.2. I have a very simple html file with php code (php5) which calls a bash script and prints the output:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $res = shell_exec("/var/www/html/run.sh");
    echo $res . " is the result";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If that html file is called on firefox, the output is

```
 is the result
```

If I directly run php with that file (`php index.php`), the output is

```
<html>
<body>
13.00
 is the result</body>
</html>
```

So, where does the result get lost?

---

edit:
The webpage source code from firefox is

```
<html>
<body>

 is the result</body>
</html>
```

---

edit: solved. bash script uses '~' which expands to wrong directory when the script is run from webserver.

Comment: Try to run with `$res = shell_exec("sh /var/www/html/run.sh");`

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20109859/1973205

Comment: The exec functions "only" return the contents of stdout. Do you get an error message when you redirect stderr to stdout?  `$res = shell_exec("/var/www/html/run.sh 2>&1");`

Comment: @VolkerK - that's it, thanks. the shell script uses '~', which is expanded to correct directory when running the php directly in bash, but directs to the wrong directory when the webserver runs the script. stupid me ;)

Comment: SImpler than expected ;-) I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec functions "only" return the contents of stdout, which is why you might miss an error message.
But you can [redirect stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script) to stdout, e.g. via

```
$res = shell_exec("/var/www/html/run.sh 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 0):

`shell_exec` does not run if you're in **safe mode**, that could be the issue