# Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64

Tags: php, android, shell, ubuntu, gradle

First off, if this belongs on Ask Ubuntu, my apologies...I'm not really sure what forum this falls under.

I'm attempting to fork and build an Android project from Github using PHP and a shell script. Basically, I'm printing out some output from a shell script I wrote into a website. When you visit the page, and press some buttons, the project is forked and built using Gradle. The PHP code runs the shell script, and then prints the output into the browser as the command runs.

However, I am getting this error as the output of my script:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
```

The script is simply running `gradle build` for now but I intend to change that later...right now, I'm just working on building the root project and outputting the result.

Here's the output if I run the command with the `--stacktrace` flag:

```
* Exception is:
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:49)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.Native.init(Native.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices.initialize(NativeServices.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices.initialize(NativeServices.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:203)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:959)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.NativeLibraryLocator.find(NativeLibraryLocator.java:39)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:41)
    ... 16 more
```

And here is the output with the `--debug` flag:

```
06:21:43.710 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
06:21:43.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
06:21:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
06:21:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
06:21:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
06:21:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
06:21:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
06:21:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
06:21:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:49)
06:21:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.Native.init(Native.java:55)
06:21:43.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices.initialize(NativeServices.java:74)
06:21:43.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices.initialize(NativeServices.java:60)
06:21:43.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:203)
06:21:43.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
06:21:43.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
06:21:43.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
06:21:43.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
06:21:43.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
06:21:43.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
06:21:43.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
06:21:43.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
06:21:43.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
06:21:43.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
06:21:43.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
06:21:43.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
06:21:43.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
06:21:43.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
06:21:43.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:959)
06:21:43.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.NativeLibraryLocator.find(NativeLibraryLocator.java:39)
06:21:43.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:41)
06:21:43.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 16 more
06:21:43.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

I did some research on this matter and found [this forum post](https://community.bitnami.com/t/gradle-doesnt-work-libnative-platform-so/40686), but it didn't give me any leads as to how to fix the issue.

Further research led me to a [Github issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/14596), which appears to be for NixOS, but I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 CLI. Also, I should mention I'm running Gradle 2.10 as well.

I also tried running `gradle -Dorg.gradle.native=false build` as well, but the outcome was the same.

Now, as far as what user is calling the script, I believe it is www-data as I'm running an Apache2 web server and PHP.

Here's a little snippet of the PHP code that runs the script, which I found on another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109859/2844992):

```
<?php
    $command = "sh /home/andrew/scripts/build.sh 2>&1";
    while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any
    $proc = popen($command, 'r');
    echo '<pre style="border-radius: 5px; padding:4px; color:black; background:#ffffff" align="left">';
    while (!feof($proc)){
        echo fread($proc, 1024);
        @ flush();
    }
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I'm at a loss now, so I'm hoping someone can lead me to a new, reliable answer.

Comment: if you run this script from terminal /home/andrew/scripts/build.sh is it working as expected?

Comment: Well, the thing is, if I fork the repo in my home directory, it works as intended. But the PHP script forks it into the web directory where the script runs `/var/www/public_html/script.php`, and then builds it.

Comment: I don't know anything about Gradle, but i would first check if all expected environment variables are also visible when you executing the script through PHP. for example GRADLE_USER_HOME etc.. .. And also would double check if these environment paths are writable by www-data user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If forking and building script working fine when is executed under your user account in the terminal then a problem is most likely with environment variables and files permissions.

1 **It could be that path defined in GRADLE_USER_HOME is not writable by www-data user**. To change home dir you could execute  `gradle -g /path/writable/by-www-user` just before running build script or use in PHP `putenv()` to amend 'GRADLE_USER_HOME'.

If you change GRADLE_USER_HOME  then also move files like gradle.properties which may be important for you build.

2 Check if gradle command can be executed by www-data

```
sudo -u www-data `gradle --version`
```

---

**How to check environment variables for www-user and for your user:**

you can use in terminal `printenv` to print environment variables. For example for www-data user that would be `sudo -u www-data printenv` and for your user just `printenv`

you can save them to files and compare

```
sudo -u www-data printenv > wwwdata-env
printenv > my-env
diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines wwwdata-env my-env
```

Then use PHP method `putenv()` - to set any missing variables related to Gradle and the project you build.

Comment: I'll experiment with this...thanks for the suggestions as this didn't occur to me.

Comment: @AndrewQuebe here is a similar issue and is also down for running with wrong user https://discuss.gradle.org/t/started-getting-libnative-platform-so-error-running-as-non-root-user/15593 ...

Comment: Calling `gradle -g` results in the same error...even if I call that as a logged in user over SSH. 

Calling `gradle --v` as www-data causes the exception as well, while calling it as my main user does not. It's installed natively...I didn't want to use the local wrappers in the project.

`/etc/environment` shows no signs of any GRADLE_USER_HOME variable...should I define one?

Comment: I think don't look into /etc/environment  just use printenv in terminal if you have GRADLE_USER_HOME  variable for your main user then you should also define it for www-data (with a new path writable by www-data )

 I will try this week to install gradle and replicate your problem with php.

Comment: Another idea is to run php-resque lib add build job to queue and execute everything from cron under your user

Comment: @AndrewQuebe I tried a similar environment but can't replicate your problem. Build through PHP working just fine ( Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS ) but I am running older gradle 1.4. Also my build.gradle is very simple and just printing "hello world". Maybe try to add into build.sh file `cd` into the correct directory with project.

Comment: I'm on 12.04 so maybe that's why.

Comment: @AndrewQuebe I don't know. To avoid such problems I usually run everything on the server with Docker and docker-compose (it's more work to setup but great time saver later). So I run always pretty much the same configuration in production and development without any nasty surprises in production ( maybe try to spin with VirtualBox a new Ubuntu machine ). Maybe it's down to this that my build in build.gradle is very simple.

Comment: I'm basically trying to build Android apps through PHP code which will be done for a userbase. I need something that I can monitor the builds for error checking, but Gradle is the only thing that compiles Android apps.

Comment: Does `gradlew` allow you to bypass specifying `GRADLE_HOME`? Mine is running on a server and I'm hoping I don't have to modify my `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved it by overriding `GRADLE_USER_HOME` enviromental variable.

In **~/.bashrc** file, add the next line:

```
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/home/www-data/.gradle
```

Where `www-data` is the username.

And restart your session or execute `source ~/.bashrc` to apply changes.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this issue because `~/.gradle` is a broken symbolic link. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using gradle 3.0 and it needs the directory mentioned in -g parameter to have execute permission. It wasn't executable when we got this error and making it executable solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, @Pawel Dubiel answer didn't work,
So I found that adding "-g gradle-user-home" to the Gradle command solved the issue.

```
gradle build -g gradle-user-home
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are missing $GRADLE_HOME variable or the directory defined in that variable is missing.
Make sure your user has write access to that directory

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is a duplicate of answers that were already given.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

In my case this was happening on Jenkins because I didn't regenerate AND source control my `gradle-wrapper.jar` file.

It's not enough to just source-control `gradle.properties`

#### My error

Newer versions of Gradle may have a more obvious error message than this.

```
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/.gradle/native/21/linux-amd64/libnative-platform.so: Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory
```

#### Credits

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/error-loading-shared-library-libstdc-so-6-no-such-file-or-directory/20379
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/11915
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/34707