# Gradle: Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

For Ubuntu

I have installed Gradle 7.2 and the `repository` directory in `/opt/gradle/` to be shared for some users:

Therefore:

```
/opt/gradle/
      7.2        rwxr-xr-x root root
      repository rwxr-xr-x root root
```

Where each directory has  `rwxr-xr-x root root`, when I execute `gradle --version` appears

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not initialize native services.
   > Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have already read:

- [Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64. #8107](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8107)
- [php - Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519643/failed-to-load-native-library-libnative-platform-so-for-linux-amd64)

Therefore if I use: `gradle --version -g ~/.gradle` it works fine - therefore it is an access permission problem/situation for each *non-root* user/group, but even when I created a common group (`developer`) for the users and added `+w` to the common group for both - I mean

```
/opt/gradle/
      7.2        rwxrwxr-x root developer
      repository rwxrwxr-x root developer
```

appears the same error - the goal is share among the users the same repository access.

What is missing to accomplish this goal?