# Starting node from PHP and getting live output

Tags: php, node.js

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output) and tried to call `npm start` or `node somejs.js`. The problem is, as soon as the first line from console.log has been printed, the eof is written into the pipe, and so the live output would terminate.

I switched to `proc_open()` and used `proc_get_status()` to monitor the running status, and I've got the exact same effect in the end. And the `running` has turned into `false` as soon as one line has been printed.

Can anybody suggest to me a better way to achieve what I'd like to achieve? (showing all live outputs from `npm start` without terminating it, until the command ends naturally).

Thanks in advance!