# executing a prompt command from within my php/html code

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have a puppeteer progam that I execute by entering `c:\myProgram>node index.js` in the command prompt.  Instead of entering this in the command prompt, I would like to have the command run from my PHP program.
Something like this pseudo-code:

```
When button is clicked,
   call function
```

Where the function will enter the command in the command prompt for me. I am using Visual Studio Code and the integrated terminal could be used instead (I think).

What code could replace `call fucntion` in my example?

Comment: `exec('c:\myProgram>node index.js');`

Comment: How is this question related to C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `exec()`, `system()` or `passthru()` functions.

There's another SO post with details on all 3. Personally I prefer passthru()

[exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)

And a slightly more advance usage of passthru() here, depends on what you need you should be covered with those two links.

[passthru() vs shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output)