# Is there a way to show live output with the exec() command?

Tags: php, logging, output, exec

I have the following code

```php
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    exec('java -jar "C:\Temp\showinfo_v2.jar"', $response);
    print '<br>';
   }
?>
```

This piece of code shows me my personal information but i have to wait like 30 seconds for it to show. I need way that it simultaneously shows me info step by step instead of giving me my whole output in 30 seconds

### What I have tried so far

- I tried changing the exec() to system() and turn output_buffering off in php.ini
- Changed exec() command to shell_exec() and also some other codes but none worked.

Comment: PHP buffers the output, this means you cannot preview it live directly in the browser like you would in a console.

Comment: Is there anything you would recommend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP reading shell\_exec live output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output)

Comment: I would recommend the solution to the question mentioned by @NicoHaase above haha, he was faster than me.

Comment: But in that thread, he used cmd which im not familiar with?

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: By replacing `$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');` with `$proc = popen('java -jar "C:\Temp\showinfo_v2.jar"', 'r');` does it work?